# which is the right idiom?

Tags: idioms

**Keep a tab** on the website for any activities.

**Keep tabs** on the website for any activities.

Which of the two, keep a tab/keep tabs, is the right idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster has an entry for the idiom [**keep tabs on**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep%20tabs%20on):

> *informal*
>   : to carefully watch (someone or something) in order to learn what that person or thing is doing
>   // We are *keeping tabs on* their movements.
>   // The magazine *keeps tabs on* the latest fashion trends.

It does not have an entry for *keep a tab on*.

Google Books Ngram Viewer also indicates that **keep tabs on** is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep%20tabs%20on%2C%20keep%20a%20tab%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20tabs%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20a%20tab%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ckeep%20tabs%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20a%20tab%20on%3B%2Cc0) in writing than *keep a tab on*.

[image: keep a tab on versus keep tabs on]

---

Although I have no problem understanding *keep a tab on*, and I'm sure I've heard that version used before, the above indicates that *keep tabs on* is at least more common. You likely wouldn't go *wrong* with the singular version, but, everything being equal, it's probably better to pick the plural version if you're not sure.